# Upcase particular letter from string in ruby

Tags: ruby, string

Lets say that I have

```
str = "ashishjambhulkar"
```

and i want to upcase only `"a"` after `"j"` which results into

```
str = "ashishjAmbhulkar"
```

How can I do this in ruby?

I have tried something like this

```
"ashishjambhulkar".split(//).map{ |x| x=="a" ? "A":x }.join('')
```

but it updates all the `a`'s in the given string.

Comment: did you try to solve it by yourself? show some code so we could help you

Comment: Hint: you'll need `String#sub`, the RegExp object `/(?<=j)a/`, the `String#upcase` function, and knowledge of Ruby blocks.

Comment: @djaszczurowski , I have updated my question, please take a look.

Comment: What do you want returned if the string is `'jajbjjj'`?

Answer (score 6):

```
str.gsub('ja', 'jA')
str.gsub(/(?<=j).{1}/) { |char| char.capitalize } #for any char that coming after 'j'
```

[More about `gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub) and [more about regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html)

Comment: Thanks buddy, I forgot about gsub for a moment :-P but you remind me.

Comment: @Leo `str.gsub(/(?<=j).{1}/) { |char| char == 'a' ? 'A' : char}` to do just for 'a'

Comment: @kiddorails, yep. The second example just for displaying that can be more dynamic. For `a` => `str.gsub(/(?<=j)a{1}/) { |char| char.capitalize }`. Thanks, I will update my answer.

Comment: No need to put `{1}` in the pattern

Comment: Also `(?<=j)\p{lower}` might be more logical since upcasing a number, a space or punctuation, or an already upcased letter probably doesn't make much sense.